# Refreshing a page when route has params in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have these routes in my App.js

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
<Route path="/people" exact component={ComponentA} />
<Route path="/people/:id" exact component={ComponentB} />
```

In my ComponentA I'm calling this action

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchData();
}
```

In this action I'm grabbing data with async/await

```
export const fetchData= () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch('api/data');
    const data = await response.json();
    const results = await data.results;
    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload: results
    });
}
```

This ComponentA also have Link to ComponentB and when I'm navigating to B by clicking Link it loads data related to a specific id, for example `/people/1`

I'm filtering it like that:

```
const c = this.props.data.filter((c, index) => index === +[this.props.match.params.id])[0];
```

But problem is if I'm reloading page `/people/1` I'm getting error because `this.props.data` is `undefined`

I can solve this by also calling the same action in my ComponentB so that `this.props.data` filled with data again. But I'm not sure that calling the same action twice is a right way to do it.

So the question is can I solve this problem without calling the same action in two components? Or is it normal way to handle this kind of issue?

Comment: Typically I end up fetching data for the route for each of my route components: eg: ComponentA will have a dispatch to fetch all the people but ComponentB will dispatch to a route for just the one person based on the ID. Then you can check if they have navigated to this ComponentB while having ComponentA already loaded and filter the user from the existing data instead of loading it again.

Comment: @Malii But the problem is that I don't have my data in ComponentA when I'm refreshing my page while on ComponentB. Because data-fetching is happening in ComponentA and I don't have anything to filter.